# Load function after whole page has been loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have a webpage made from html where the body is loaded externally using jquery load function. So inside the external code, there's a div with `id="main"`, how do I load another external code into div with `id="main"` after the main body code and the whole page is loaded? Please help.
This is the code for the whole body of the page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#body").load("body.html");
        });
```

Inside the body, there's a div like this

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

So I have another external html where it should go into the "main" div with name main.html
i have tried putting this in the head and after the div but it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#main").load("main.html");
        });
```

If you guys don't mind, visit this link and look at the source code and help out, sorry
http://proxcent.com/test.html

Comment: Please, add some code here. Thanks.

Comment: have you considered using document.ready?

Comment: Edited, sorry for that, any ideas?

Comment: This is answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33548074/1414562  You have to use ajax method complete callback  `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`

Answer (score 4):

you can use onLoad method. See that:

### On DOM ready (not completely resources loaded, only DOM tree)

```
$(document).ready();
```

### On page totally loaded (images included)

```
$(window).on('load', function() { ..... });
```

Comment: or just $(window).load

Comment: like this?
$(window).on('load', function() {    $("#main").load("main.html");
});

Comment: That's not answering question, OP is making ajax request to load body content

Comment: @A.Wolff when I answer, OP does not share any code. So you can see pre-edited answer and you understand...

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Oh then that makes completly sense ;)

Comment: Yes, and sorry if this answer finally is not the correct.

Comment: Nothing's working, please help out by visiting the link and checking my code. Sorry. The code is put in the head
http://proxcent.com/test.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the div with id as "main" exists on the page with `$('#main').length > 0` and then load whatever external code that you have with `$('#main').load()`

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
        if($('#main').length > 0){
           $('#main').load('/yourExternalCode.html');
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery load method takes a callback function as a second (or third if you want to send through data as second argument) argument, which is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

```
$("body").load("body.html",function(){
    // load more external content
    $(this).find("#main").load("main.html");
});
```